# Closure Operator and Set Operations

Tags: general-topology, analysis

In Engelking, General Topology stand the following exercise:

Show that for any sequence $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ of subsets of a topological space we have
$$
 \overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i} = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} \overline{A_i} \cup \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} \overline{\bigcup_{j=0}^{\infty} A_{i+j}}.
$$

I have no idea how to show this, I can't even show that the right side yields a closed set, because when I build the complement I got infinite intersections, which aren't necessarily open. Any hints how to solve this exersice?

Comment: Presumably at least one of the indices should be $j$

Comment: you are right, i corrected it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$For each $i\in\Bbb Z^+$

$$\cl\bigcup_{j\ge 0}A_{i+j}\subseteq\cl\bigcup_{j\ge 1}A_j\;,$$

so

$$\bigcap_{i\ge 1}\cl\bigcup_{j\ge 0}A_{i+j}\subseteq\cl\bigcup_{i\ge 1}A_i\;,$$

and therefore

$$\cl\bigcup_{i\ge 1}A_i\supseteq\bigcup_{i\ge 1}\cl A_i\cup\bigcap_{j\ge 1}\cl\bigcup_{i\ge 0}A_{i+j}\;.$$

Suppose that

$$x\in\left(\cl\bigcup_{i\ge 1}A_i\right)\setminus\bigcup_{i\ge 1}\cl A_i\;.$$

For any $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ we know that

$$\cl\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_k=\bigcup_{i=1}^n\cl A_i\;,$$

so for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ we have

$$x\in\left(\cl\bigcup_{i\ge 1}A_i\right)\setminus\cl\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i=\left(\cl\bigcup_{i\ge n+1}A_i\cup\cl\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i\right)\setminus\cl\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i\subseteq\cl\bigcup_{i\ge n+1}A_i\;;$$

do you see that this implies that

$$x\in\bigcap_{j\ge 1}\cl\bigcup_{i\ge 0}A_{i+j}$$

and hence that

$$\cl\bigcup_{i\ge 1}A_i\subseteq\bigcup_{i\ge 1}\cl A_i\cup\bigcap_{j\ge 1}\cl\bigcup_{i\ge 0}A_{i+j}\;?$$

Answer (score 2):

The inclusion (RHS) $\subseteq$ (LHS) is trivial, so I will give you a hint for the reverse inclusion:

Assume that $x$ is not in the right hand side. Then there is a $j\ge1$ such that $x\notin\overline{\bigcup_{i=j}^\infty A_j}$, i.e. there is a neighborhood $V$ disjoint from this union starting at $j$. But for each $i\ge0$ there is also a neighborhoods $U_i$ disjoint from $A_i$. Now intersect $W:=V\cap U_1\cap...\cap U_j$. Does this $W$ intersect the union of all $A_i$?

Answer (score 2):

I am still looking through your solutions, but meanwhile I came up with another for the direction (LHS) $\subseteq$ (RHS). Can you please look if its valid?

Let $x \in \overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i}$, suppose $x \notin \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\overline{A}_i$ (otherwise we are finished), then we have to show for all $i$ that $x \in \overline{\bigcup_{j\ge i} A_j}$. Suppose there is some $i$ for which $x \notin \overline{\bigcup_{j\ge i} A_j}$, then as $x \in \overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i} = \overline{\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1} A_i} \cup \overline{\bigcup_{j\ge i} A_i}$. It must be that $x \in \overline{\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1} A_i}$, but because $x \notin \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\overline{A}_i$ and $\overline{\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1} A_i} = \bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1} \overline{A_i} \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} \overline{A}_i$ we have a contradiction.

Comment: This is a very nice argument. :) In fact, I believe it's better than those provided by other answers.

Comment: I think that is basically the solution I provided. One assumes that there is a union starting from a certain index such that $x$ is not in the closure of this union, and one also assumes that it is not in any of the individual closures. Then since for finite unions closure and union commutes, it would be neither in the closure of the union starting from the special index nor in the closure of the union of those finitely many $A$'s before that index, so it cannot be in the closure of the whole union.